# Cual es la mejor forma de almacenar documentos e imágenes?

Tags: base-de-datos, webservice, servidor, aws, storage

Tengo pensado crear una aplicación sobre temas financieros, como prestamos crediticios, etc. En esta aplicación necesito almacenar información sobre los usuarios, esto incluye documentos como por ejemplo imagen de su identificación, o un comprobante de ingresos, etc.
Mi pregunta es... Cual es la mejor forma de almacenar ese tipo de documentos, guardarlos en una base de datos como mysql?, guardarlos en el servidor y tener la ubicación del archivo en la base de datos? o usar algún otro servicio?

Comment: Bienvenido @MiguelPartida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), favoreciendo así tus chances de obtener una buena recepción por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola como experiencia **nunca guardar documentos binarios como imágenes** o cosas asi **dentro de una base de datos**, nunca lo hagas, por otro lado alguien podrías indicarte en el mismo proyecto que uses por ejemplo el mismo hosting donde esta alojado el sitio web, ésto es bastante inseguro sobretodo si son documentos tan privados, cualquier alteración o ataque a tu servidor o hosting involucrará que roben los datos y peor aún los eliminen (bueno creo que el robo es peor).

La mejor opción es utilizar Amazon S3 en el cual puedes generar un bucket y subir todo tipo de archivos, en donde puedes indicar permisos de acceso edición y eliminación por dominios, es una de las formas más seguras.

Si te hackean el sitio web tu proyecto no deberías tener problemas ya que los documentos están en otra ubicación y de perder la base de datos, y ésta la respaldas cada hora o diariamente no tendrás dificultades para re establecer todo el proyecto.

Te lo digo como experiencia propia, una vez me paso ajjaja

¿POR QUE NO GUARDAR EN BASE DE DATOS?, por que no están hechas para eso y solo lograrías dejar lenta la base de datos y muy muy muy pesada

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en. Opiniones no se deben responder pues terminan cerradas, de hecho ya lleva dos de cinco votos para ello

Comment: ok entiendo BetaM